# Why in the console application when doing screenshots html pages is a growth of memory

Tags: c#, memory-management, console, browser, screenshot

Why c # console application, when in the cycle to take screenshots of html pages - there is a growth of number of the memory occupied by the application? The more it works, the more the volume increases.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleAppScreenShot
{
class Program
{
static String pathApp = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath.ToString();
static string url = "http://www.ya.ru";
static int width = 960, height = 1380;
static bool isDownloadScreenComplete = false;

[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("hi");

    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            isDownloadScreenComplete = false;
            RunGenerateScreenshotThread(url, i);

            int number = 0;
            while (!isDownloadScreenComplete) // 5-ти минутный цикл ожидания скрина
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                if (number > 3000)
                    throw new Exception(string.Format(" Ошибка цикла ожидания потока закачки снимка экрана. Ожидание составляет: {0} минут.", (number / 600).ToString()));

                number++;
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ошибка: {0}", ex.Message);
    }
}

static void RunGenerateScreenshotThread(string url, int count)
{
        var th = new Thread(() =>
        {
            WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
            // Set the size of the WebBrowser control
            wb.Width = width;
            wb.Height = height;

            //wb.DocumentCompleted += GenerateScreenshotCompleted;
            wb.Navigate(url);
            while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) { System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents(); }
            try
            {
                // Get a Bitmap representation of the webpage as it's rendered in the WebBrowser control
                Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(wb.Width, wb.Height);
                wb.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, wb.Width, wb.Height));
                wb.Dispose();

                // Save Thumbnail to a File
                bitmap.Save(string.Format("d:\\1\\Screenshot{0}.png", count), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                bitmap.Dispose();

                count++;
                Console.WriteLine("Natigated to OK {0}", count);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ошибка: {0}", ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                isDownloadScreenComplete = true;
                Application.ExitThread();   // Stops the thread
            }
        });
        th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        th.Start();
}
}
}
```

---

Flow with WebBrowser after some iteration hangs waiting for about 5 minutes:

```
while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) 
 { System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents(); }
```

where the value of the state is:

```
wb.ReadyState == Uninitialized or Interactive
```

eventually returns the page "Navigation canceled" - or returns it has a 5 minute delay.

1. Why WebBrowser component using IE as the seventh version, if my system is IE8?
2. Why WebBrowser component ceases to give the page?
3. Why memory volume increases as a result of the application and takes about 800 mb?

My task is to save the page is displayed to the hard drive using the console application. Maybe we can somehow or another in pdf format in which to save, so you can see the HTML content of page.

I will be glad to any valuable comment.

```
class Program
{
static string url = "http://www.whatbrowser.org";
static int width = 960, height = 1380;
static int count = 0;

[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("hi");

    try
    {
        int number = 1000;
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            var th = new Thread(obj => RunGenerateScreenshotThread((string)obj));
            th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            th.Start(url);
            th.Join();

            count++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("All successfully completed!");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.ToString());
    }
}

static void RunGenerateScreenshotThread(string url)
{
    try
    {
        using (WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser())
        {
            // Set the size of the WebBrowser control
            wb.Width = width;
            wb.Height = height;
            wb.Navigate(url);

            while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) 
              { System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents(); }

            if (wb.DocumentTitle == "Navigation Canceled")
                Console.WriteLine("Natigated ERROR {0}", count);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Natigated OK {0}", count);
            }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        Application.ExitThread();   // Stops the thread
    }
}
}
```

Comment: How much memory are we talking here?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I'd be extremely dubious of using any method described [as](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowserbase.drawtobitmap.aspx): "This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code. This method is not supported by this control."

Comment: Also, with the manual `Dispose()` handling, you may leak important resources if an exception is thrown. I'd hope you'd have told us if that was happening though.